# Global gitignore v project

Tags: web-development, development-process, git

We have several web projects within our organisation - using different frameworks and with many different developers.

Each developer might use a different ide and use different operating system etc and my question is that should the project gitignore include ide and os specific ignores?

such as netbeans, phpstorm, ds etc

Or should we rely on individual developers ignoring the files relevant to them

Comment: https://www.gitignore.io/ lets you create a gitignore depending on your IDE

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to check in the IDE created files, as you don't want `Thumbs.db` or `.DS_Store`. By making every developer create their own version, you are adding more work and the risk of laziness at absolutely no gain. Having a few extra lines doesn't hurt, and helps you make sure you are not creating files that could interfere with other developers' workflow.

Most of the open source projects I have explored the source do indeed follow this, explicitly gitignoring all these files. See, for example, [Numpy.](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/.gitignore)